# How to make changes in vue v-model syntax in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a little task in vue.js and I want to change the syntax of `v-model` to `model`, or something else with webpack and vue-loader. I tried directives but that's not what I need.

This my example:

```
<input v-model="anyVarible">
<input model="anyVarible">
```

Comment: You could try creating a custom html property like so `<input :model="anyVariable" v-model="anyModel />`.

Comment: ty for your comment but i try this and my task rejected

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` is just a syntax sugar on setting & getting the data - prepared for all the input types:

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on
> form input, textarea, and select elements. It automatically picks the
> correct way to update the element based on the input type. **Although a
> bit magical, v-model is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on
> user input events, plus special care for some edge cases.**

*Source: [Vue 2 v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)*

That means, you can change `v-model` to something else, but then you have to handle the cases:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      vmodeltext: null,
      modeltext: null,
      vmodelcb: null,
      modelcb: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInputText({
      target: {
        value
      }
    }) {
      this.modeltext = value
    },
    handleInputCb({
      target: {
        checked
      }
    }) {
      this.modelcb = checked
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="vmodeltext" /><br /> With v-model: {{ vmodeltext }}<br />
  <hr />
  <input type="text" :value="modeltext" @input="handleInputText($event)" /><br /> With modeltext: {{ modeltext }}<br />
  <hr />
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="vmodelcb" /><br /> With v-model: {{ vmodelcb }}<br />
  <hr />
  <input type="checkbox" :checked="modelcb" @change="handleInputCb($event)" /><br /> With modelcb: {{ modelcb }}<br />
</div>
```

So, essentially you don't need to change `v-model` with Webpack or a loader - just write the code in the way you need.

Comment: thanks for answer but i try this way unfortunately it's rejected

Comment: @Asam rejected by what? by who?

Comment: i want do this task for showing my skill for using with webpack and vue-loader the person who ask me to do this he says we can change v-model or v-if syntax to any thing else with webpack but idk how i try to ask here maybe find a way to do this

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to create a [plugin](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/) yourself for achieving this, similar to `babel-plugin-jsx-remove-data-test-id `